# Scala specs: nest in-statements

Tags: scala, specs

is it possible to nest following specs test code

```
"ClassX" should {
  "throw an IllegalArgumentException if n < 0" in {
    ClassX(-1) must throwA[IllegalArgumentException]
  }
  "throw an IllegalArgumentException if n > 50" in {
    ClassX(51) must throwA[IllegalArgumentException]
  }
  "throw an IllegalArgumentException if n == 35" in {
    ClassX(35) must throwA[IllegalArgumentException]
  }
}
```

in another in-Statement like:

```
"ClassX" should {
  "throw an IllegalArgumentException if" in {
    "n < 0" in {
      ClassX(-1) must throwA[IllegalArgumentException]
    }
    "n > 50" in  {
      ClassX(51) must throwA[IllegalArgumentException]
    }
    "n == 35" in  {
      ClassX(35) must throwA[IllegalArgumentException]
    }
  }
}
```

Because it is easier to read and write

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  See http://code.google.com/p/specs/wiki/DeclareSpecifications for an overview of all the ways you can structure Specs specifications.

Comment: Ok. thank you very much. My code above works very well. I had an other mistake in my code thus the test failed.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer code like this:

```
 "My Component" >> {
   " some general function" can {
     "do stuff that I like" in {
       //…
     }
     "do stuff others like" in {
       //…
     }
   }
 }
```

but as you might notice there are a gazillion ways to do it.